# html/css: Draw borders through a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Mybigcell</td><td>col3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is to draw a border around the first column, that means around col1 and the left part of Mybigcell. The border thus has to run through the middle of Mybigcell.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is the content for all of the cells dynamic? If not, which ones are static?

Comment: There is no "left part" of the cell which has `colspan="2"` (notice to add the hyphens). So no element available to  draw the border you want on that row. You will have to restructure your markup.

Comment: Ideally, everything is dynamic. If it's not possible for a dynamic layout I can settle for static widths, though.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6t4tns2v/1/)? Can you add a sketch or something with the desired output?

Comment: If you know the widths, I was thinking you could use a pseudo element overlaying the table.

Comment: hey, nice!  @Oriol, that is somewhat what I was thinking... And looks like it can handle dynamic widths as well. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @Oriol: Yes, pretty much like this, although I would need finer control where to draw the border (in your fiddle it is automatic for all cells) - I have added a third column to the question to prevent cheating ;-)

Comment: You can adjust @Oriol's solution to work only on the first and second column by using `tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1):before,
tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2):before` as the selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use absolute positioned pseudo-elements to achieve this.

Just use the CSS below and add `class="border"` to some cell. Its column will obtain a border.

Basically, it works like this:

- We will insert some absolute positioned pseudo-elements with `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`. Their containing block will be the table rectangle (`position: relative`), so the pseudo-elements will grow to cover all the column.
- These pseudo-elements will be inserted at the beginning of the cells (`::before`). Assuming left aligning inside the cells, they will be aligned at the desired position.
- Note they can't be aligned using `left: 0` (and we can't use `::after` with `right: 0` neither) because the containing block is the table, not the cell. If the containing block was the cell this would be more reliable, but the borders wouldn't fill all the column.
- Therefore, if a cell has a `border` class, a pseudo-element will be inserted in that cell (the left border), and in the following one (the right border).
- But if the cell with the `border` class was the last one in the row, it would have no right border, because there is no following cell.
- To fix that, I use the `:last-child` pseudo-class to detect this case, and then I insert an `::after` pseudo-element with `left: 100%`. As mentioned above, it will be aligned relatively to the table instead of the cell. But assuming there is no missing cell in the row, that won't matter because the right edge of the cell and the right edge of the table will coincide.
- Finally, I do some small adjustments using negative margins, to make it pixel perfect.

```css
table {
  position: relative;    /* Containing block for the borders */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 1px;
  padding-left: 2px;     /* Increase by borderWidth */
}
.border:before, .border + :before, .border:last-child:after {
  content: '';           /* Enable the pseudo-element */
  position: absolute;    /* Take it out of flow */
  top: 0;                /* From the top of the table... */
  bottom: 0;             /* ...to the bottom of the table */
  border-left: 1px solid;/* This produces the border */
  margin-left: -2px;     /* Same as td's paddingLeft, in negative */
}
.border:last-child:after {
  left: 100%;            /* Place it at the right */
  margin-left: 0;        /* Remove the margin set previously */
}
```

```html
<table>  <tr>  <td class="border">col1</td>        <td>col2</td>                 <td>col3</td>                                </tr>
         <tr>  <td colspan=3>Mybigbigcell</td>                                                                                </tr>  </table><hr />
<table>  <tr>  <td>col1</td>                       <td class="border">col2</td>  <td>col3</td>                                </tr>
         <tr>  <td colspan=3>Mybigbigcell</td>                                                                                </tr>  </table><hr />
<table>  <tr>  <td>col1</td>                       <td>col2</td>                 <td class="border">col3</td>                 </tr>
         <tr>  <td colspan=3>Mybigbigcell</td>                                                                                </tr>  </table><hr />
<table>  <tr>  <td>col1</td>                       <td>col2</td>                 <td class="border">col3</td>  <td>col4</td>  </tr>
         <tr>  <td colspan=4>Mybigbigbigcell</td>                                                                             </tr>  </table>
```

If you want to customize the width of the borders or the paddings, see the SCSS:

```css
/* Parameters */
$borderWidth: 1px;
$padding: 1px;

/* Code */
$sum: $borderWidth + $padding;
table {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: $padding;
  padding-left: $sum;
}
.border:before, .border + :before, .border:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: $borderWidth solid;
  margin-left: - $sum;
}
.border:last-child:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `.border:before, .border:after`?

Comment: I was going to add some `:nth-last-child(n+2)` shenanigans, but this is better.

Comment: @RobinJamesKerrison Because the `.border:after` wouldn't be aligned to the right. I could use `right: 0` and `td{position: absolute` to fix that, but then `top:0; bottom:0` wouldn't make it grow to fill all the column.

Comment: I tried it here and it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/6t4tns2v/3/ Your solution is super and the only edge case I can think where it would fail is in on the last cell of a row.

Comment: @Robin: That is not a problem because you can always add another column to the table.

Comment: @RobinJamesKerrison In that case seems to work, but compare this other table [withyour code](http://jsfiddle.net/6t4tns2v/4/) and [with mine](http://jsfiddle.net/6t4tns2v/5/)